# Open a pop box in a web page

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a page that is asking the user for information.  After then hit submit a function is run to validate the information that the user put in.  If they don't add something to a required field then it throws a alert and makes then enter something in that field before they are allowed to continue.

Instead of an alert I want the pop up to show them the field they need to enter information into and not let them leave the current page until they have entered the information.

The field in question is a drop down.  Basically what I want the pop up to look like is a pop up box and in the center is the drop down list and a submit button.  But I don't know how to create the pop up from my validation function.  Any suggestions.

Comment: So look into modal windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) helpful.